# Server 2003 R2 - II6- granting access to website via IP with subnet range

Tags: windows-server-2003, ip, iis-6, subnet

We are trying to allow for a client to connect to our website. By default we are Denying all access except for those with the specified IPs we have configured to run, everything before has just been a single IP address. However now we must implement a range of IPs and rather than input thousands of records we want to use the group of computer options in the Grant Access page. However we have it configured to work off of the IP 72.21.192.0 with a subnet mask of 255.255.224.0 They are unable to connect. Looking over our IIS logs they are receiving a 302 error which is the same behavior anyone should get whom is unauthorized to view the page in question. The IP address coming in is 72.21.217.2, so it should be well within the rage of acceptable IP addresses.

I'm at a loss as everything I look up tells me to do what we are doing. So any insight would be appreciated. Especially because I'm a software guy not hardware.

Thanks!

Comment: 302 is not an error - if the users are being blocked by an authentication check, the code should be 401 or 403.  How's the 302 redirect configured?

Comment: Yeah 302 is not an error, but not the desired result. It basically redirects them to a page that says that they do not have access. To keep people off of the main page.

Comment: Right, but that's not what will be thrown by IIS when it blocks a user due to those authorization rules.  So do you know where the 302 is coming from?  Is there dynamic content running within IIS?

Comment: Yeah it seems like the other component is what is wrong as there was a misconfiguration with that. Things seem to be working now. Thanks!